# Error running docker-compose: django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I am writing a Django Rest API and till today I was using venv until today I decided to switch to docker environment. And I'm not able to connect to the database in docker. Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydatabase

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

This is the .env.dev file:

```
SECRET_KEY=its_a_secret
DEBUG=1
SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2
SQL_DATABASE=mydatabase
SQL_USER=postgres
SQL_PASSWORD=postgres
SQL_HOST=db
SQL_PORT=5432
```

On my local environment..

I have mydatabase running on a postgres server on port 5433.

But when I `docker-compose up` I get the following error[image]

Here is the configuration for databases in my `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": os.environ.get("SQL_ENGINE", "django.db.backends.sqlite3"),
        "NAME": os.environ.get("SQL_DATABASE", os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3")),
        "USER": os.environ.get("SQL_USER", "user"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("SQL_PASSWORD", "password"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("SQL_HOST", "localhost"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("SQL_PORT", "5432"),
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `settings.py` look like, specifically `DATABASES`?

Comment: It gets it from the .env.dev file